# Django: Can't get homepage to display correctly TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

well I'm working on a new Django project and am having a real hard time getting the index.html page to display correctly. Any advice on what to change to get it to display correctly?

I'm getting the error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /

index.html
```

my settings for each file are below.

myprojectname/myprojectname/settings.py

```
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates/static')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_ROOT + '../templates'
)
```

myprojectname/myprojectname/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', 'apps.views.index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

myprojectname/apps/views.py
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', locals())
```

I'm new to Django too so don't hate! :) I'll gladly admit I'm a noob...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your template directories:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

Your folder structure should be similar to:

```
project_name/
    project_name/
        settings.py
        templates/
            index.html
```

The folder structure is especially important!

And define your template loaders if you haven't already:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )),
)
```

I've wrapped the standard loaders with `cached.Loader`, which funnily enough just caches pre-compiled templates.

Also, while I'm here, fix your root URL:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'apps.views.index'),
```

Note the extra `$` terminating the end of the regex, otherwise this first URL will match every single URL, and none of the others will get a chance to match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_ROOT + '../templates/'/
)
```